# Can I subscribe to this.props.navigation.state.params?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am wonder if in `screenA` I have an object `data = {}` that will be changed dynamically, can I receive changes in `screenB` by just sending this props from `screenA` through `this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB', {data})`?

And in `screenB` to have a `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` to get this changes through something like `nextProps.navigation.state.param.data`

Or there is a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy, just as you said: send some data `navigation.navigate('screenB', { data })` and receive it in the screenB as `navigation.state.params.data`.

I agree with @FurkanO you probably show use Redux instead to control all the state of your app, but for simple stuff I think isn't necessary!

I made a simple snack demo to show you: [snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-56671202](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-56671202)

[image]

Here some code to follow up:

#### Home Screen

```js
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    colors: ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.colors.map(color => {
            return <Text>{color}</Text>;
        })}
        <View>
          <Text>Details Screen</Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to Details"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', { colors: this.state.colors })}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Details Screen

```js
class DetailsScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    colors: [],
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ colors: this.props.navigation.state.params.colors });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.colors.map(color => {
            return <Text>{color}</Text>;
        })}
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

> #### Update

The question's author requested an update to add a `setTimeout()` to see the exact moment when the data is on the other screen, so it will look like this:

```js
componentWillMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ colors: this.props.navigation.state.params.colors });
    }, 3000);
}
```

[image]

Comment: try to use this in HomeScreen and navigate to DetailsScreen before changing the color `setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({colors: ['red', 'blue', 'black']})
    }, 5000)` What I need is to get changes in second screen

Comment: I don't actually understand why you'd like to add a  `setTimeout()` to get the data in the other screen when I am actually getting it. Check the snack: [snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-56671202](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-56671202)

Comment: As I said in the description I don't just want to get data in the other screen. I want to receive the changes in the other screen. The data is changed dynamically so without going back to get the changes I need to see them in the second screen once they are changed. So as @FurkanO said `redux` is my friend in this case but I was wondered is there is another option to avoid this

Comment: Man I don't know why you are struggling with it, I just added the timeout to show you, when the data it's changed, just what you needed it, check out it the example again, I am going to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onWillFocus` of [`NavigationEvents`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html), which fires whenever the screen is navigated to.

```js
_willFocus = () => {
  const { navigation } = this.props
  const data = navigation.getParam('data', null)
  if (data !== null) {
    /* do something */
  }
}

/* ... */

render () {
  return (
    <View>
      <NavigationEvents onWillFocus={_willFocus()}
    </View>
  )
}
```